# Blogger RSS feed: comments not updating

Tags: rss, blogger, feed

*Hello,*

I use blogger for almost one year. For a long time I didn't need RSS, but now I need both posts and comments feed.

First ([posts feed](http://www.blog-fnb.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default)) works great when I post a new article, RSS updates in seconds.

But [comments](http://www.blog-fnb.blogspot.com/feeds/comments/default) **RSS never updates**.

*What am I doing wrong?*

**TECH INFO:**

[Validator](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.blog-fnb.blogspot.com%2Ffeeds%2Fcomments%2Fdefault) output of comments feed.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the solution! Go to the **Settings** -> **Google+** -> **Turn off Google+ comments**.
After you disable they, they will be deleted from your blog.

Google provides these details:

> If you used Blogger comments, they will remain on your blog. Third
>   party commenting systems might not be retained when you enable Google+
>   comments.

In short, RSS readers cannot see Google+ comments.

I hope it helps you :).